# In Java, specifically Floating-point, what is the difference between float and double?

Tags: java

I've seen examples of the terms "float" and "double" being applied to different scenarios and seem to understand that bits and bytes serve some role, but I cannot find a clear explanation of what the difference is. Memory constraints seem like the cause of such differentiation

Comment: doubles store twice as much information

Answer (score 0):

float has size of 4 bytes with range 3.4e-038 to 3.4e+038 . whereas  double has size of 8 bytes with the range 1.7e-308 to 1.7e+308.  float allows 6 decimal digits whereas double allows 15 decimal digits.

please go through this link for more info https://www.javatpoint.com/float-vs-double-java .